# How to remove specific char from datagridview in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I copied data from one datagridview to other and want to delete specific char in copied data. How can I do it
my code:

```
int n = 0;

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count != n + 1)
    {
        dataGridView8.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView8.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    }
    n += 1;
}
```

Comment: You could add `.Replace("k", string.empty)` after `.ToString`

Comment: thanks! that works, and if I want to delete last 3 characters in each row in copied data?

Comment: In your code it would be `row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Replace("k", string.empty).Substring(myString.Length-3);`

Comment: thanks, but what does it mean with "myString"? in my context?

Comment: See my comment below. It includes the full command for what you want.

Comment: oh many thanks, have a nice day!